# PC Spins and Mounts 2.5" drives but not 3.5" drives

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata, desktop

Using SATA connectors from the motherboard and PSU I cannot get my PC to spin up a 3.5" desktop drive.

```
Specs:
MOBO: ASRock ab350
PSU: 600W
GFX: 1060 Mini
```

I've checked for firmware updates for my MOBO, I'm up to date. I have confirmed that the 3.5" drives work on other computers.

Any idea what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was because I was using white label HDDs that I salvaged from a Western Digital NAS. I solved it using the tape method as described here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYiCR.jpg